# Create new row when condition is not right in postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have executed this query:

```
SELECT
       id, user_id, device_id, date(creation_date_time) as day, shape
from olocations
where user_id = 'd0edfc59-9923-44c3-9c34-ef5aad3cb810'
  and device_id = '89984320001811791540'
group by id, creation_date_time
ORDER BY creation_date_time ASC
```

And it is return this:
[image]

All data is ordered by time and ready to distance comparison.
It is possible to check distance between points (point1 with point2 - point2 with point3 and so on) if it was for example more than 10 meter, make new row and points that have correct condition inserted as a group into one row else?
I know that `st_dwithin` command can check distance but how can i change row when distances between geo points more than 10?

Comment: can you provide data and desired results?

Comment: You can use the `lag` window function to compare with the previous row. That enables you to tell when a new group begins.

Comment: This my query but how could i start new group when distance not appropriate http://codepad.org/1FZSx3t3  @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I gave you the hint - use window functions. The inner query will use `lag` to indicate a new group, the outer query will use `count` to enumerate the groups. Once you have the group number for each row, the task is simple.

Comment: dude `lag` returns value evaluated at the row, how can indicated a new group? i do not undrestand :-( can you write similar query @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Well, `CASE WHEN distance(shape, lag(shape) OVER (ORDER BY creation_date_time)) < 10 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS starts_group`.